# Are INSERT values encoded with SET NAMES, SET CHARACTER SET?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

Using MySQL, I have set my connection charset to UTF-8:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';
```

That way I'm getting back everything as UTF-8, even for the tables which have a latin1_swedish_ci collation (there are a few).

When I'm sending UTF-8 INSERT strings, to insert into one of the latin1 tables, will the values be encoded to latin1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First preference:  Use the programming-language-specific connection parameter for 'charset'.

Second preference:  `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` -- (no quoting needed).

The `CHARACTER SET` on the column/table is *independent* of this connection / `SET NAMES`.

The connection / `SET NAMES` declares what encoding is used for the bytes in the *client*.  `INSERT`/`SELECT` will convert between that and the column/table declaration, hence your utf8-latin1 observation.

"When I'm sending UTF-8 INSERT strings, to insert into one of the latin1 tables, will the values be encoded to latin1?" -- To reiterate, the bytes you send *must* be encoding according `SET NAMES`.  They will, if possible, be correctly converted to latin1 in the table.  I say "if possible" because Chinese, Emoticons, etc, *cannot* be converted to latin1, since latin1 handles a very limited set of characters (only enough for Western Europe).